# Using web API with parameters in JSON with FromUri or FromBody

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to create an example with web `api`. I want the received parameters in JSON with `fromuri` or `frombody`. When I create the client I want to send an object or JSON with the information.

In my web API I have this

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromUri]Peticion peticion)
{
     return Ok(peticion);
}
```

and in my client

```
Peticion obj = new Peticion();
obj.cliente = 2;
obj.factura = 22;
string DATA = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);

var client = new HttpClient();
HttpContent content = new StringContent(DATA, UTF8Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

HttpResponseMessage message = 
client.PostAsync("http://localhost:57418//api/Deudor/",content).Result;

if (message.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
   string result = message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

But I need in my client received the JSON. In the web API I need to receive two parameters (cliente, factura) and in my client I need to received the information of that client (name, invoice etc) in JSON.

I used postman, and received the JSON with the information. But in my client C# I couldn't.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of using .net core or framework, you can use HttpClient to send Get and Post requests to your API.

POST request:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(YourObject), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
client.PostAsync("your url", content);
```

Then you can get content [FromBody]
You can use Post requests and get parameters from url, but it's better to use get in that case.

Get request:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.GetAsync("your url/api/controller/id/{id}");
```

In both cases you need to set your routes for your methods with request types (GET, POST).
e.g: in the get example above:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")
public class SomeController
{
  [HttpGet]
  [Route("id/{id}")]
  public someGetMethod(int id){
    //do something with id here...
  }
}
```

Comment: HttpResponseMessage response= await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:57418/api/Deudor/",content);
var Petiction = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Peticion>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

Answer (score 0):

In Web API, if the controller method's parameter is not a "simple" type, it tries to get the value from the body. So I think you want to remove `[FromUri]` in your `Post()` parameters because you're actually sending that information in the request body.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: But how can I use JSON? I don’t need to use string, omg or whatever in the method...